# Get all posts starting with an alphabet in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, alphabetical, posts

I'm trying to create directory listing in which at the top there will be links...from a-z
some what like this:

[A](http://#) [B](http://#) [C](http://#) [D](http://#) [E](http://#) ...............[V](http://#) [W](http://#) [X](http://#) [Y](http://#) [Z](http://#)

When a user presses on A, all the posts with titles starting with A should come, whats the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone asked this on wordpress.org check the link for your answer with sample source.

[first-letter-posts](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/first-letter-posts)

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement an SQL request that would use the "LIKE" filter:

```
SELECT * from post WHERE post.title LIKE 'A%';
```

This request will give you all the posts starting with the 'A' letter.

Comment: Thanks.I knew the SQL request.But wanted the wordpress specific way.